# Argparse: what is the difference between "sys.argv[1]" and "args.input"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hierarchy, argparse, sys

I'm learning how to use argparse and it's a labyrinth for me.

I have a code that works: if I run `python Test.py .` it prints all files in hierarchy using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import argparse
import sys
import glob

#parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                             
#parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input',help="input one or more files",nargs='+',metavar=None                           
#args = parser.parse_args()

def dirlist(path, c = 1):

        for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*")):
                if os.path.isfile(i):
                        filepath, filename = os.path.split(i)
                        print ('----' *c + filename)

                elif os.path.isdir(i):
                        dirname = os.path.basename(i)
                        print ('----' *c + dirname)
                        c+=1
                        dirlist(i,c)
                        c-=1


#path = os.path.normpath(args.input)
path = os.path.normpath(sys.argv[1])
print(os.path.basename(path))
dirlist(path)
```

But, as I want to understand how argparse works I want to run the code using `python Test.py - input .`

But nothing works.

I know I'm close, I have written a sort of Frankenstein code which is commented.

Where am I wrong? I feel I'm so close to the solution...

Comment: Please post text as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: I don't know if this comment will be helpful to you, but if you want to understand how argparse work, you can always [look at source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py).

Comment: Explain "Nothing works". Your test.py works with `python Test.py [path]`. Your options `-` and `input` (or possibly, `-input`) do nothing because that code is commented out.

Comment: `args.input` will be a list due to `nargs='+'` while `sys.argv[1]` will be a string I believe.

Comment: Post two indented code blocks instead of one with comments. And show the output that made you think code not working. There is a guess about `'-input'`: it should be `'--input'`

Comment: When testing `argparse` code, I recommend using a `print(args)` statement.   Do this before trying to use `args` attributes, so you understand what it is producing.

Comment: @khelwood: the code is posted as text. Just the output is posted as image

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Yes, I can see that. It's still text posted as a screenshot.

Comment: @khelwood: I like when you put -1 on my question for silly reasons, can you do it again, please?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani If I could, I would.

Comment: OK @khelwood, I want to be mature now. Don't you think the important part is the code and the output is completely irrelevant for search engines? Maybe you are right and I'm doing things wrong. 
Please tell me because I do this in purpose and I want to understand if I'm doing something wrong. 
The last thing I want to do is pollute StackOverflow

Comment: I don't know why anyone would post a block of pure text as a screenshot. If you've got a block of text on your computer, it should be less effort to paste it into your question as text (in a `<pre>` block if necessary) than to screenshot it. If your program output is important to your question (which I assume it is because you've included it at all), why prevent (for instance) blind people on this site from being able to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @match for the right tips.
Problem was I was using `nargs='+'` in the argparse definition

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import argparse
import sys
import glob

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                              
parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input',help="input one or more files",metavar=None)                     
args = parser.parse_args()

def dirlist(path, c = 1):

        for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*")):
                if os.path.isfile(i):
                        filepath, filename = os.path.split(i)
                        print ('----' *c + filename)

                elif os.path.isdir(i):
                        dirname = os.path.basename(i)
                        print ('----' *c + dirname)
                        c+=1
                        dirlist(i,c)
                        c-=1


path = os.path.normpath(args.input)
print(os.path.basename(path))
dirlist(path)
```

The code works now!